# issues with invalid syntax my_real_escape_string

Tags: php

```
$sql = "UPDATE 'biz_feedback'
    SET
        advice1 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($advice1)."',
        advice2 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($advice2)."'
    WHERE
        review_id = '".$_POST["review_id"]."'
        AND biz_id = '".$_POST["biz_id"]."'
        AND username = '".$_POST["post_review_username"]."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Error, query'.$sql.'failed'.mysql_error());
```

Brings about this error

```
Error, query

UPDATE 'biz_feedback'
SET
    advice1 = 'No issues but would be good to have more help to hand so person doesn\'t have to go hunting for help',
    advice2 = ''
WHERE
    review_id = '1117'
    AND biz_id = '2371881'
    AND username = 'user'

failed
```

Error, queryUPDATE 'biz_feedback' SET advice1 = 'No issues but would be good to have more help to hand so person doesn\'t have to go hunting for help', advice2 = 'no more advice thanks' WHERE review_id = '1117' AND biz_id = '2371881' AND username = ''failedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your server version for the right syntax to use near ''biz_feedback' SET advice1 = 'No issues but would be good to have more help' at line 1

Comment: Having trouble expressing this statement

Comment: `= '".mysql_real_escape_string (.$advice2)" WHERE`  the `.` looks misplaced.

Comment: Oh god where to begin, almost everything is wrong in what you just posted.

Comment: Aside from the invalid syntax, you really shouldn't be using the MySQL extension in 2015, but MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables.... learn the current approach to interacting with a SQL database, not an old, deprecated approach that won't exist in PHP by the end of this year

Comment: **WARNING:** you're using a deprecated database API. Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)

Comment: Thanks for the warnings, can anyone help with the correct syntax, thanks. (Im not a developer I just have this urgent issue) @Daan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misplaces your dots here `.mysql_real_escape_string (.$advice2)`.
The last one should be just after `(` so it'll look like this `.mysql_real_escape_string($advice2).`

Next problem with your query is `'` sign around table name. You should skip it or use backtick ` instead.

Comment: Thanks Elon... Brings this error: check the manual that corresponds to your (MariaDB) server version for the right syntax to use near ''biz_feedback' SET advice1 = 'No issues but would be good to have more help' at line 1

Comment: @Mark update your question. Or add error message in second comment ;)

Comment: Thanks Elon, I know its painful for you :-)

Comment: Man, thanks so much Elon. Nice easy one for you to fix, much grateful person here have a great day man.